# Efficient way to demo out a few square feet of half inch too high concrete

Tags: concrete

There is a very poorly laid basement slab that is high by as much as half an inch in some spots.  Is there any means short of renting one of those large/expensive standing professional concrete grinders to knock these sections down?

This is the backup plan (day rental):

[image]

The 10" walkbehind will certainly get the job done but I like having my own tools around if possible:

- we might need it on 2 or 3 separate days
- driving to/from the rental place is as much a "cost" as the rental price
- after done with the job can re-sell tools for a moderate "loss" on craigslist or similar

But I'm not certain there were a reasonable DIY alternative to this. An angle grinder with a 5" diamond concrete grinding wheel and manually squirted water does a fine job cutting down 1/8 inch ..

[image]

but 1/2 inch .. not so much..

btw please remember your respirator at the least - and a ventilator system if it's available.

Comment: @statueuphemism We have 1000sqft to deal with - some of which is an inch low. We are definitely doing another series of pours in sections at different elevations - there will need to be transitions among them.  We will put in the the proper forms to section them out.  But we don't want to add another 1/2 inch to the entire  affair.  Might be ten or fifteen square feet that need to be ground down

Comment: For just a few square feet on a budget, a sledge hammer does wonders.

Comment: Do you mean to demo out the entire 4 inch slabs in those sections and repour completely ? I can't think of anything less subtle than the sledge (and less apt to cut out only a fraction of the material) . But in that case i'd go with wet saw and jackhammer to do those areas. That's actually another backup plan not mentioned above. I have the sledge and 2inch cut depth saw (7 inch blade), a 4inch cut depth saw (14" blade)  is arriving in two days.

Comment: You can do the job well, you can do the job quickly and you can do the job cheaply but you can't do all three. Take the hit and hire the correct tool for the job.

Comment: Or discover clever tricks of the trade using less glamorous tools . Maybe no such animal in this case.   More often though we have one day where the brunt of the job is done (maybe get that 10inch walk-behind). but couple days later some smaller sections: nice to hear let's say intermediate level approaches that mix modest efficiency with "let's use what tools we have on hand"

Comment: If there's enough area to need the rental for 2 days, then rent for 2 days up front or extend the rental (usually available and no more expensive than 2 days up front). Hit the big stuff with the big tool, then do the smaller areas with a smaller tool? Don't forget that the drive & rental costs offset hours on your hands and knees with a small grinder, and even with a good mask & hearing protection, you're going to be uncomfortable for days later - knees, back, lungs, ears, eyes... Makes a 2nd day of rental seem pretty cheap to me.

Comment: 2 days rental is well outside budget.  i'd demo out a small area instead given i'll have the 14" saw on Tuesday.  I'm still hunting around for some intermediate idea

Comment: criss-cross cuts with a saw and a chisel to remove raised material quickly ... grind to make smoother ... slide saw on level rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have some experience in this type of work for a few jobs.

- Get the cuts started in a small section with a 14 inch wetsaw.
- Demo out all the way through to the underlying dirt
- Once we have it dug out all the way then my electric jackhammer does an efficient job of extending the hole in any direction desired. It's not a straight-straight line in the concrete but in many case a precision cut is  not required

There are other jobs where clean straight line cuts are important. In that case cut two parallel lines with the 14" wet saw all the way from one end to the other. Then chisel or demo [ impact hammer or jackhammer] the middle out by starting at either end. The concrete tends to oblige and just fall out after getting a running start on it.